# call HttpClient GetAsync but app freezes seconds and works as sync mode

Tags: c#, winforms

Below is my code to get an HTML page

```
  public static async Task<string> GetUrltoHtml(string url)

    {
        string s;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            //Console.WriteLine("!!!"+result.StatusCode);
            s = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; //break point


        }
        return s;
    }
```

the line

```
var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
```

causes app freeze seconds and work as sync mode

Your comment welcome

Comment: `var result = await client.GetAsync(url); return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` -- [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=net-5.0)

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method.

So getting `Result` is a blocking action. You should use `await` instead.

```cs
s = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

(`Result` is helpful when the result is ready and you just want to get it. Or in some cases you want to block the thread (but it's not recommended).)